# How do you cumulate every n records in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains the Rainfall collected every 15 mins at a site. To convert this to an hourly total I would like to be able to find the sum of every 4 rows.
i.e. if my data was:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I would like it to return:

```
10
26
```

I have 500 odd pieces of data. The code below is what I have tried:

```
e = c['Rainfall'].groupby(c.index//4).cumsum()
```

Where the DataFrame C holds the Rainfall collected data.
At the moment it outputs the exact same data it gets in.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index//4)['column_name'].sum()` replace `column_name` with the actual column name of the column which i think is `Rainfall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.index//4)['column_name'].sum()
```

thanks to @anky_91